# Convert an array of objects with 1 value each into simple array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I have an array of Objects , each object always gets 1 value. And I don't know the keys nor the length.

```
$result = {array} [2]
  0 = {stdClass} [1]
    email = "2"
  1 = {stdClass} [1]
    email = "31"
```

I have tried it with

```
$emails = (array) $result;
```

But that will not change it of course.

Also get_object_vars was not the solution for me.

Comment: by `each object always gets 1 value` you mean that all elements of the array are objects with one attribute/field ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way for me.

As it is an array of objects and it stores only one value (email) I can simply foreach over the array like this.

```
$emails = [];
foreach ($results as $result){
  $emails[] = $result->email;
}
```